# Multiple substrings in query

Tags: mysql

My end goal is to get e-mail addresses from a database. However, my first query retrieves ID's that correspond to the e-mail addresses in a different table. However, the query returns the ID's in the following way:

```
1:FOO,2:FOO,3:FOO,...
```

The way to retrieve the e-mails is to do

```
SELECT email from emails where id in (SELECT id from other_table)
```

However, since the IDs from `other_table` are in the `ID:FOO` format and the e-mail address table has them without `:FOO`, I don't get the e-mails back.

I also tried

```
SELECT email FROM subscribers where CONCAT(id,":FOO") in (SELECT id from other_table)
```

However that doesn't work. I think I need to be able to retrieve the ID's from `other_table` without `:FOO` to make this work. How can I remove all `:FOO`'s from the results?

Comment: REPLACE(id, ":FOO", "")

Comment: @RemcoK. for some reason `(SELECT REPLACE(id, ":FOO", "")  from other_table)` is just giving me back 1

Comment: @RemcoK. never mind I got it to work

Answer (score 0):

Use **GROUP_CONCAT**

```
SELECT `email` FROM `emails` WHERE `id` IN(
   SELECT REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(`id`), ':FOO', '') FROM `other_table`
)
```

Comment: What if some of the fields are `:FOO` and others are `:BAR`? Is there a way to use Regex to match all of them?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql